# Cisco 4404 Wireless Controller Load

Tags: cisco, wifi

I'm not a Cisco admin, so this is a little out of my depth.

I'm trying to troubleshoot what seems to be a congestion problem on a wireless network. We have an access point outside one room that is currently reporting hangs and issues with the laptops; when I connect to the controller (the 4404 wireless controller) via the web interface and look at that specific access point, it is showing a "load profile" failure.

The rx utilization is 14, tx utilization is 16, channel utilization is 32, and attached clients is 20.

Are these number showing that it is way overloaded (like a Unix system load would probably indicate)? Or is this a percentage amount, so it really isn't all that bad? Or am I looking at the wrong statistics altogether?

Comment: What is the model of the AP, that is just as important as the controller. Also, what firmware revision are you on (it should be the same for the controller and the AP)?

Comment: Believe they are Aironet 1131AG for the access points. Software versions match on controller and access point.

Comment: What is that software version?

Comment: Also, how are your management, AP management and Virtual interfaces configured? Are you using link aggregation so that you only need a single AP management interface, or do you have AP managers defined individually.

Comment: software version is 5.2.178.0. I'm not sure of the exact configurations put in by my boss and the consultant (I'm asked questions kind of as a third-string)...I just get the information from the web interface to the controller that gives some statistics about the various AP's connected to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attached clients is a count. The others are percentages.

20 clients on one AP radio is a lot (depending on what the users are doing). I would suggest adding more APs to that area.

Comment: Actually, 20 on a single Cisco LAP is fine, they spec it up to 50, with a recommended max at 25 for most models.

Comment: That is, assuming your actual wired infrastructure can handle that, but it should unless it's a total mess.